# How to fetch a google search results feed with a python script and not be identified as a bot?

Tags: python, rss, urllib, bots

I am trying to import results from a Google Search results rss/xml feed into my website but every time I run the python script I get a message from Google:

> Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network.
>   This page checks to see if it's really you sending the requests and
>   not a robot.

The script uses urllib to download pages and works with other rss feeds.

Doesn't really make sense as I thought rss feeds were supposed to be consumed by software (bots), I left the script over the weekend and ran on Monday morning but still got the message so I am not hitting their servers too much.

I can load the feed in my browser though and I can also download the feed using wget on the server?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the URL you are using? Also, see http://www.labnol.org/internet/rss-feeds-for-google-searches/19944/ - "The only limitation is that you can call this URL [no] more than 100 times in a day."

Comment: I am using the following url:

http://news.google.co.uk/news/feeds?hl=en&safe=on&gl=uk&q=mining+OR+metals+OR+oil+OR+gas+OR+lng&biw=1266&bih=757&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&um=1&ie=UTF-8&output=rss

Answer (score 3):

You could use some HTTP sniffer (like fiddler) or any protocol sniffer (tcpdump, wireshark) to sniff your network traffic to Google and check if your urllib request and wget/browser requests differ. Also check and compare all the cookies and HTTP-headers of both requests. And remember , that for IPs with big number of requests to Google - google sends captcha every N requests , so if you need to parse it's content - you possibly need to use some proxies for Google parsing.

Comment: Yes, I could do all that but surely Google doesn't expect humans to be loading up xml feeds in their browsers every 20 minutes, rss feeds were designed to be consumed by software.

Comment: @anteatersa Google doesn't like bots. It's only goal is to serve browsers. If you're building a bot to poke Google, one way or other Google is gonna stop you.